# Does Visual Studio 2010 ship with jQuery support?

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2010

Those lucky enough to have access to a Visual Studio 2010 - does it ship with jQuery support for ASP.NET solutions? The beta did not have it yet and I could only read [promises](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/webdevelopmentprerelease/thread/4be951cc-c360-453a-a86c-b9a6a24f27cf) from Microsoft that they will have it included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jquery is a part of ASP.NET MVC and MVC is a part of(at least RTM) VS distribution

Comment: Indeed, it's an MVC initiative, not just a VS one.

Comment: Just to add, I can confirm that VS2010 Beta 2 ships with ASP.NET MVC 2, including jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Conference 2009 was held at the Microsoft NERD Center in Boston Massachusetts. There was a talk by some Microsoft folk that showed the integration of jQuery into VS 2010. They are also going to support a few select jQuery plugins, including jQuery Validation, which will hook directly into the VS server-side validation. Their new cdn for hosting this type of thing seems to also be directly related.